# MSBuild working in debug mode, but not release mode - and another interesting anamoly

Tags: msbuild, release, mode

I have a basic MSBuild script which includes a step for project compilation/build.  Looks like this:

```
....
    <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReferences Include="loc1\Project1.csproj"/> 
    <ProjectReferences Include="loc2\Project2.csproj"/>
    <ProjectReferences Include="loc3\Project3.csproj"/>         
</ItemGroup>
....
    <Target Name="BuildProjects">
    <Message Text="Beginning main project build"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReferences)" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);ProjectBuild=$(ProjectBuild);AppDir=$(AppDir)">
        <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="AssembliesBuilt"/>
    </MSBuild>      
    <!--<CallTarget Targets="BuildToolkit"/>-->
</Target>
```

`Project3.csproj` is a .NET 3.5 Web Services project.  The configuration is passed in on the command line.

First was a problem with System.Linq not being able to be resolved; I remedied this by creating a reference to `System.Core` directly in the project file (apparently this happens often and requires this fix).

Now, when I build this project in debug mode, all is well.  However, when trying to build in release mode, it fails like this, with may of these messages pertaining to all kinds of assemblies:

`Considered "c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VST040\v8.0\MyReferencedProjectAssembly.dll", but it didn't exist.`

This happens many times over for a number of references.  Oddly, after this happens, I switch back to debug mode and it fails to build again after the release mode happens.  I have to remove the offending Project3 from the MSBuild file, run again (which works), and re-add the offending Project3 back into the file before it works again in debug mode.

I'm stumped.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like your project references are not set up correctly. Your projects are build in the wrong build order and build failed "sometimes". It has nothing to do with debug/release mode, I guess.

Check your csproj files if it contains correct project references to other projects. For example if Project2 is depending on Project1:

project2.csproj:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\loc1\Project1.csproj">
  <Project>{79FB10A6-6CD9-46D4-9463-319B8CBD82FE}</Project>
  <Name>Project1</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Where Project is ProjectGuid of project1 (from project1.csproj)